# Play audio based on listview item clicked

Tags: android, audio, mediarecorder

My app has a DetailView from a ListView. Inside detailView I can record, store in SD card and play back the audio file (outputFile), the problem is that its always the most recent audio recorded regardless of the item clicked in my listView. How can I associate the recorded outputFile to the selected item clicked detailView? I hope this makes sense. Thanks in advance.

```
play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) throws IllegalArgumentException,SecurityException,IllegalStateException {
            MediaPlayer m = new MediaPlayer();

            try {
                m.setDataSource(outputFile); //AUDIO DATA SOURCE outputFile
            }

            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                m.prepare();
            }

            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            m.start();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Playing audio", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Comment: The problem is in the adapter and the data entered into the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want in entirety but the following would work asnwer your question.

You can use a hashmap to store the audio assigned to the button.

```
private HashMap<String, String> hm;

public MyAdapter(){
   hm = new HashMap<>();
}
```

After you have recorded and stored the audio, assign a counter to the recordings 0, 1,2,... And store the following

```
hm.put("Position" & counter, outputFilePath);
```

Then in your play.OnClickListener use the following as dataSource

```
m.setDataSource(hm.get("Position" & itemPosition));
```